# как в python написать функцию которая ищет в массиве слово которое было введено пользователем

Tags: python, массивы

у меня есть база данных с фильмам как можно грамотно  реализовать функцию поиска чтобы он работал быстро и нашел все подходящие слова

Answer (score 2):

Все задачи решаются довольно просто - разбиением их на отдельные шаги, которые понятно будет как сделать по отдельности. И всё это можно нагуглить, вам нужно только сложить этот конструктор из кубиков. Итак, гуглите, как в `Python`:

- Написать функцию
- Получить ввод от пользователя
- Передать параметр в функцию
- Что такое массив (на самом деле список - в чистом питоне есть только списки), как его описать
- Как найти слово в списке слов

Потом всё это собираете вместе - и решение задачи готово.

Comment: Ну все, теперь ждите пять разных вопросов отдельными темами. А нет, шесть - забыл "как собрать все вместе". :-)

Comment: @passant Я открыл ящик Пандоры (((

Comment: Я все это знаю у меня есть база данных с фильмами хотел подключить ему нормальный поисковик. Не понял как это можно грамотно реализовать чтобы он работал быстро

Comment: @RahmatjonHikmatullayev Ну так это совсем другой вопрос, его и нужно задавать